# 'Will transfer' or 'will be transferred'?

Tags: passive-voice

1. I was notified you **will transfer** to the marketing division.
2. I was notified you **will be transferred** to the marketing division.

My colleague said that no 1 is correct, but I argued because it sounds strange to me. Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: The verb transfer is both a transitive and  intransitive verb. So both the sentences are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3):

Definition of TRANSFER

- transitive verb (He will **be transferred**...)

> a :  to convey from one person, place, or situation to another :  move, shift
>
> b :  to cause to pass from one to another :  transmit

- intransitive verb (He will **transfer**)

> to move to a different place, region, or situation; especially :  to withdraw from one educational institution to enroll at another

Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transfer)

Both are right but you can have a look at the two definitions and usages (transitive vs intransitive) and see which one is more suitable.

I think the addition of 'that' would make your sentences better:

I was notified **that** you will transfer to the marketing division.

I was notified **that** you will be transferred to the marketing division.

Comment: I've touched up the formatting in your answer, to make the definitions pop and included a link for MW so the OP or someone else could easily access additional information :-) (I hope that you don't mind). The addition of 'that' makes the sentence **sound** better, but grammatically it is just fine without it. I'm sure that this is what you meant, but the OP might not know that.

Comment: @Lucky: Thanks. That edit surely made my answer look much better. Yes, I totally agree that the addition of  'that' is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the **intransitive use** means *that the subject is the one initiating the transfer* and the **transitive use** means *that the someone else initiated the transfer of the subject*. This difference can easily be understood with inanimate objects like '*money*' for instance:

1. The money will **transfer** tomorrow.
2. The money will **be transferred** tomorrow.

In the 1st sentence the money cannot do the action *(it can't go anywhere by itself)*. In the 2nd sentence someone will transfer the money *(somebody will send the money somewhere)*.

Animate objects on the other hand can do the action themselves.