# Will be expanded OR will expand

Tags: passive-voice

> It's probable that markets **will be expanded** in the future.

> It's probable that markets **will expand** in the future.

Which sentence is correct, or I should use?

Comment: Either is correct and possible, they just mean slightly different things.  "Will be expanded" is the passive voice, indicating that the markets will be expanded by someone else.  "Will expand" is the active voice, and just indicates that the markets will grow.  More than that we can't say without knowing more context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Will transfer' or 'will be transferred'?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58686/will-transfer-or-will-be-transferred)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "to expand" has a *transitive* definition meaning "to *make* larger".  "To expand" also has an *intransitive* definition meaning "to *become* larger".

Your examples are one of each.  The first sentence is the transitive verb's passive form, which implies *conscious action* -- someone will *make* the markets grow.  The second sentence is transitive and simply means the markets will grow, but does not imply this is a result of any conscious effort.

Other examples:

> This constant noise must be stopped!  (transitive passive)
>
> The noise will stop (intransitive) after we are finished.
>
> If you don't stop it (transitive active), I will!
>
> Ok, since you want it to stop (intransitive)  we will stop it (transitive).